# spring boot app in google cloud 500 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, mariadb

my repository method:

```
public List<PublicAnnouncementListItem> getAllPublicAnnouncementListItems(String Country, String City, String DateRange, String UID) {
        String from = DateRange.split("-")[0];
        String to = DateRange.split("-")[1];
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT `AnnouncementID`, `AnimalName`, `Species`, `Breed`, `DateRange`, `AnimalImage`, `Country`, `City` FROM `announcement` JOIN `user` ON `announcement`.`OwnerID`=`user`.`UID` WHERE `OwnerID` = `AssignedKeeperID` AND `user`.`UID` = `announcement`.`OwnerID` and `Country`=? and `City`=? and OwnerID!=? and STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DateRange`, '-', 1), '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d.%m.%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d.%m.%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DateRange`, '-', -1), '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d.%m.%Y') AND  STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d.%m.%Y');",
                BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(PublicAnnouncementListItem.class),
                Country,
                City,
                UID,
                from,
                to,
                from,
                to
        );
    }
```

my controller method:

```
    @GetMapping("/api/getAllPublicAnnouncementListItems/{Country}/{City}/{DateRange}/{UID}")
    public List<PublicAnnouncementListItem> getAllPublicAnnouncementListItems(@PathVariable("Country") String Country, @PathVariable("City") String City, @PathVariable("DateRange") String DateRange, @PathVariable("UID") String UID) {
       return announcementsRepository.getAllPublicAnnouncementListItems(Country, City, DateRange, UID);
    }
```

sql query more readable:

```
SELECT 
`AnnouncementID`, 
`AnimalName`,
`Species`, 
`Breed`, 
`DateRange`, 
`AnimalImage`, 
`Country`, 
`City`
FROM 
`announcement`
JOIN `user` ON `announcement`.`OwnerID`=`user`.`UID`
WHERE
 `OwnerID` = `AssignedKeeperID` AND
 `user`.`UID` = `announcement`.`OwnerID` 
  and `Country`=? and `City`=? and OwnerID!=? 
  and STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DateRange`, '-', 1), '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d.%m.%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d.%m.%Y') 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DateRange`, '-', -1), '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d.%m.%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d.%m.%Y');
```

query is for getting records based on specified date range

Tell my what can be wrong with my code. **When I run my app on my local computer it works** but If I deploy my spring boot app to google cloud I got an error: `` java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'and STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DateRange`, '-', 1), '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN STR...' at line 1 ``. The interesting is that **when I try to perform my query in php my admin - I mean in database connected to my spring boot app - everything works fine and query doens't return any error.**

Comment: My guess is that value substituted for OwnerID comparison causes the issue. Btw you use mariadb, not mysql

Comment: which comparison do you mean? this one OwnerID!=?. If so what's wrong with it?

Comment: You need to check what gets substituted into the parameter

Comment: I modified my query the following way: ...and `Country`=? and `City`=? and OwnerID!='NameSurname'... and it still throws the same exception. of course I commented UID in my java function:
                City,
                //UID,
                from,

Comment: We can't see the actually executed sql statement, so we cannot be sure what's going on before the position of the error. The error usually occures just before the part of the code indicated by the near part of the error message.

Comment: Although the first two criteria in the where clause do not make sense. One is the same as the join clause and the other should be in the join clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've been deploying app on googlecloud I didn't notice that I chose incorrect project adam314pi@cloudshell:~/quickadoptionapiserver (**wrong_project**)$. That's why I've been updating wrong project and when I changed project to the correct one everything started to work